# Fast and reliable communication between programs

Tags: python, matlab, communication

#### Problem

Let's assume I want to process an online data stream (e.g., from a webcam) using Matlab.

Depending on the data, the program running in Matlab will output a binary signal [0,1] after each iteration of whatever algorithm is running for data analysis.

Simultaneously, I am running a Python program, which does a visualization on the computer screen. Crucially, this visualization is dependent on the binary signal from Matlab.

#### Initial Solution (to be improved):

The most straight forward but also slow and error-prone method I can imagine would be that Matlab (over-)writes a file after each data-analysis-iteration and that python reads that file for each visualization-iteration.

#### Question

What is the fastest (around 10ms to max. 50ms) and most reliable method to establish this communication ...

- ... on a single computer?
- ... on a network via ethernet? (i.e., each program runs on a different computer on the same network)

Comment: _What is the fastest (<10ms)..._ Are we really supposed to be talking about milliseconds? Would 11ms be inacceptable and 9ms good?

Comment: I am interested in different methods that are out there and how they compare in terms of speed and reliability/robustness. The 10ms are just an indication that anything far off (let's say, 100ms) is not very useful for what I need.

Comment: If you have a hard threshold on the acceptable time, you should be looking into real-time operating systems. Otherwise, there is no guarantee on the time processing any input will take.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way that I found yesterday was using [labstreaminglayer](https://github.com/sccn/labstreaminglayer). Which is apparently using a combination of UDP and TCP/IP to stream data on a network using a buffer.

It can be used with Python, Matlab and other languages ... in particular the [Python interface](https://github.com/chkothe/pylsl) seems very straight forward and easy to install with `pip install pylsl`.

I would still be interested in a general outline of methods for this kind of communication or a pointer to some good introduction about that.